# Calculus - convergence of the challenging series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln^{8}(n)}{n}\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi)}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I struggled with determination of convergence of the following challenging series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\ln^{8}(n)}{n}\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi)}{2}\right)$$

Found hint that the use derivative should help in this problem (don't see how...).

Solutions/help in this problem very needed (spent 4 days and still no progress...)

Comment: I am very interested in seeing proper solution to this problem. I would be very thankful for help!

Comment: Notice how the Sine function acts at those points... For the terms $n=0,1,2...$ the Sine function gives $-1,1,-1,1...$ and can thus be replaced by $(-1)^n$

Comment: For a start, figure out what $\sin((2n+1)\pi/2)$ _is_. Try $n=1,2,3,4$ and see what happens.

Comment: Isn't it just Leibnitz criterium?

Comment: From there the alternating series test should work

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the $\sin$ needs to be removed first. Using the periodicity of $\sin$,
$$ \sin \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right) = \sin (n\pi + \pi/2) = (-1)^n
$$
Since $\log$ grows slower than any power,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^8}{n} = 0
$$
Now you can apply the alternating series test.

Answer (score 1):

The sine function in each term alternates from $+1$ for $n$ even to $-1$ for $n$ odd. Thus, the series is an alternating series. Remember the famous test for an alternating series: the series converges if and only if the absolute value of the terms tends to zero.

So check if $\dfrac{\ln^8(n)}{n}$ converges to zero. That will be clear, if you understand the end-behavior of the logarithm function. If not, you can use L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

using mellin transform is aproximate to
$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \zeta ^{(8)}(-2) x-\frac{1}{48} \pi ^3 \zeta ^{(8)}(-4) x^3$$
when x =1 get your serie